# Feasible size for an itinerant military

Tags: internal-consistency, military

The story I'm writing exists in a world technologically equivalent to the late middle ages and is about an itinerant militia that makes their living primarily through hunting large and dangerous animals. I'd like the group to be large enough that the average band of brigands or highway men wouldn't mess with them on the road but not large enough to be considered an army. Ideally I'd like it to be 100 men, including support staff.

Is it feasible that a group that large could sustain a life on the road, never staying in one place more than a few months?

Comment: think about how often they move, how big are the cities/villages they visit, and how many extra people such cities could feed. Or rather how much food a village is willing to give up to get rid their unfriendly neighborhood monster.

Comment: What makes them "military" as opposed to "a group of well-armed hunters"?  Are they paid and hired by the central government?  Or by the towns they save from dangerous animals or the families that buy the meat?

Comment: they are a martially trained band of mercenaries, they are hired by towns or communities primarily to defend against menacing wild life but would certainly take on a job involving a hostile neighboring community.

Comment: This question bugs me. It feels like there's just enough information to make it seem answerable in an objective fashion, until I start trying to figure out a way to estimate the number. Then it becomes murky. It has already been flagged for closure as _primarily opinion-based_, but I'd be inclined to lean towards _too story-based_. I'll come back to this later for another look.

Answer (score 2):

3-5, maybe 10, people; a military with no central base from which to operate and organise is, of necessity, going to be cellular in structure. Each cell is a small self-sufficient group that would, in a centrally controlled organisation, take orders from the leadership directly, with no central co-ordination they're going to be completely independent.

Comment: Thanks Ash this was a big help and saved me a heap of agonizing rumination.